# Working on a pull request, while updating master

Tags: git

I've been working on my own branch, but then I've got a pull request from someone else which I had to merge to `master`.

After merging their pull request into `master`, I couldn't merge my own `dev` branch into `master`! So what I've done is:

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/master && git pull && git push
```

Then my branch's `git log` looked like this:

1. My branch's commits.
2. The other contributor's commits.
3. My branch's commits (from point 1), they repeat themselves.

What am I doing wrong? How do I avoid this issue? How do I fix the mess that I've created in my `git log`? My whole `git log` looks horrible because of it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what your goal was. You have 2 options really:

1. If you want to rebase your branch - that is replace the existing commits on that branch with new ones starting from `origin/master`, then you don't need the `git pull` in your command. Then `git push -f`, or possibly create a new branch from that point and just `git push`. This will result in: (in order)

   - old master history
   - new master changes
   - your branch commits
2. If you want to preserve the commits and add a merge point with master, you can replace those commands with `git checkout your_branch ; git fetch ; git merge origin/master`. You'll get the same conflicts to resolve as when you're trying to merge your branch to master. But on the other hand, they're the same conflicts you have to resolve when rebasing. This will result in: (in order)

   - old master history
   - your branch commits
   - merge with new master changes

As for how to fix it, you can find your old branch in `git reflog`. Look for the commit from before your rebase and make a branch out of it. You have the choice of either starting a new branch that way, or resetting your old branch to that commit.

Comment: Your second option was the solution for me - I checked out from it (found the hash from `git reflog`) and followed the `git fetch; git merge origin/master`, thank you!